# Convert list array to array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Anyone can help on how I can convert searchedItem values array structure same as postByBusinessName array structure? I just need to use it in setting up my state in react js.

[image]

Comment: What have you attempt4ed

Comment: Please update the question with input as well as the desired output.

Comment: @HassanImam its already on my question. I need to do searchedItem  same as output structure of postByBusinessName

Comment: Please post your data instead of an image of it

Comment: Instead of an image, post the data in the textual format, also this should work for your case `Object.assign(...o.searchedItem);`

Comment: Iterate over the collection by using `map` (like in Jquery) to initialise new collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use `Object.assign` with `spread syntax`, to create an object

```
const res = Object.assign({}, ...searchedItem);
```

or you can simply use `Object.assign` with `.apply`

```
const res = Object.assign.apply(null, [{}].concat(data));
```

Comment: Thanks this is working for me. I used object.values that's why I got an error

Comment: Object.values gives you the values for keys in an object and not for an array